# ssrs_migration.rss file

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anybody have the ssrs_migration.rss file for RS.EXE (SSRS Reporting Sevices). Can't find it anywhere (Microsoft dropped the ball on this one) and I need to move a bunch of reports. Even if I you can post the VB as text so I can copy it. That'd be great. Thanks!
OR... If you know of a better way that'd be awesome too! I cannot deploy strait out from the project in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to Github to get your file.  That's a treat to work with too.

Click the Raw button (why they don't have a "download" button is beyond my comprehension) and then Safe the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I copied the text without using the "raw" link, and I kept getting a bunch of errors when executing commands.  I copied the "raw" text and updated the 'ssrs_migration.rss' file and the commands worked after that.